# match everything except three consecutive double quotes

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I'm looking for a regex to parse *everything but three consecutive double quotes*. The problem is that when I use a normal negative lookahead the consecutive double quotes get gobbled and there it doesn't really match what I want.

Let's assume I have the following text:

```
Lorem Ipsum
"""
sdsdfgsdf
"""
bar
```

And want to *linewise-regex* to match the first, third and fifth row, but not the `"""`.

I've tried the following regex: `/(?!""").*/`, but that's when the double quotes get gobbled.
Trying to match one double quote at a time using `["]` fails too: `/(?!["]["]["]).*/`

I'm using Python to match the regex.

Any ideas how I can make this regex work?

Comment: `re.findall(r'^(?!"{3}$).+', s, re.M)`? See https://regex101.com/r/piWLvQ/1

Comment: You want to process your input line-wise and a line with nothing but 3 consecutive double quotes should be sorted out? Do a string comparison.

Comment: What if it is a line with four double quotes ?

Comment: It also seems you may simply `[x.strip() for x in s.split('"""')]` ([demo](https://ideone.com/84AzDu)).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, but I need a regex :)

Comment: `"""` is a regex pattern, too. `[x.strip() for x in re.split('"""', s)]`

Comment: Globally replace `(?m)^"""(?:\r?\n)?` with nothing. Then split the string on newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unanchored pattern `(?!""").*` will match any char 0+ times if what is on the right is not `"""`. Since it is not anchored, it will match after the first `"` in `"""` because at that position the assertion will succeed.

You have to use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and add `.*` to the negative lookahead if those 3 double quotes can not occur in the string:

```
^(?!.*""").*$
```

Or only use the 3 consecutive quotes if those are the only chars in the string.

```
^(?!"""$).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxX10H/1)

Comment: more simpify `^(?!"{3}).*$`

Comment: @frankegoesdown That is also possible of course,  `"""` is 3 characters :-)